# GSON MalformedJsonException

Tags: json, android, gson

I am using GSON to serialize my REST responses.
I am getting this response from the server:

```
      {"idUser":1,"nom":"kaddour","prenom":"hanedi","login":"enit","password":"hanedi","genre":"f","adresse":"impasse chaabene merhbene","codePostal":8050,"tel":20333473,"active":1,"panneaux"}
```

and GSON is throwing a `MalformedJsonException` due to the last `panneaux` that has no value.
How can I treat such response ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot handle such exceptions , since the response is an invalid JSON format and cannot be parsed at all using standard libraries.

You may write your own parser that parses character by character and discard keys without values.

Comment: do u happen to know where there is such a type of response ?

Comment: Basically , there must be something wrong with the server response , I've not seen any such Json.  If this is the only Json that's malformed from the server , it's easy to parse this single line kind of Json.. but little tricky to parse nested Json and json arrays

Comment: actually `panneaux` comes from a bidirectionnel `OneToMany` and its supposed to return an arry of objects but I always get that response. I am working on other server responses that work just fine.